# Trouble with dynamic arrays and finding the sum of values

Tags: c++, arrays

So as I explained in the title i'm having trouble trying to get the sum of an array. I've just now learned how to create dynamic arrays and I did some searching on how to calculate the sum. I don't believe I fully understand what is going on to calculate the sum.

```
// Final Grade Calculator

#include <cstdlib>

#include <iostream>

#include <cmath>

#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    double minor, quiz, major;
    int minorG, quizG, majorG;

    minorG = 0;

    cout << "Final Grade Calculator" << endl;

    cout << "Input minor grade weight percent." << endl;
    cin >>minor;

    cout << "Input quiz grade weight percent." << endl;
    cin >>quiz;

    cout << "Input major grade weight percent." << endl;
    cin >>major;

    // Three grade categories
    minor = minor/100;
    quiz = quiz/100;
    major = major/100;


    for(int i = 1; i <=10; i++){
        cout << "Input a minor grade. (Max=10)" << endl;
        cin >>minorG;


        int *minorGA = new int[minorG];

        minorG+= minorGA[minorG];
        cout << "Currently: " << i << " Grade(s)." <<endl;
    }
    cout << "Minor Sum: " << minorG << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This is what I have so far and the trouble I am having is within the for loop which is where my array is and where I am trying to get the sum of it. When I compile and run I get a sum of 138,427. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I wasn't sure of a better way to do it as of now. I figured plugging the data into an array and getting the sum of what was typed would be the best way to go about creating this calculator. But, no you're right I don't believe I understand exactly what that was doing. Not sure if I'm searching incorrectly because I can't find an explaining of what that actually does.

Comment: If you're just trying to get the job done, use `std::vector` if you really need a dynamic array.

Comment: This allocates an array of minorG integers: `int *minorGA = new int[minorG];`

Comment: This increments minorG by the value of 1 item past the end of the array minorGA: `minorG+= minorGA[minorG];`  Since it is 1 item past the end of the array this is undefined behavior. Although even if you picked a valid index since you did not initialize any values in your array you will most likely be adding some random garbage to minorG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're over-complicating things with dynamic arrays. I'll explain what you're doing, and try to provide help for what I think you're trying to do.

In your code `int* minorGA = new int[minorG];` you are allocating memory for `minorG` amount of `int`s. There are two problems here:

1. You are accessing an element outside of the memory you allocated. When you allocate 10 elements, you can access elements 0-9. Trying to access 10 is undefined behaviour (you are trying to access parts of memory that could contain anything).
2. The values stored in this array are just whatever is in memory, so when you are attempting to increment `minorG` by the amount of one of these, it's just whatever is in memory at the time.

A separate problem is that you are not deallocating the memory, but some might argue that it isn't really a problem.

You should just be able to have the following to perform what I think you're trying to do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    int inputtedNumber = 0;
    cout << "Enter a number" << endl;
    cin >> inputtedNumber;

    // add that number to some tally:
    finalTally += inputtedNumber;
}
```

Or if you are trying to store the elements in an array, you can use the following:

```
const int maxElements = 10;
int grades[maxElements] = {}; // this will construct all elements with 0. Without this, the elements may contain any number.
for (int i = 0; i < maxElements; ++i)
{
    int inputtedNumber = 0;
    cout << "Enter a number" << endl;
    cin >> inputtedNumber;

    // Store the number
    grades[i] = inputtedNumber;
}
```

In saying that, it will be better to use [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/?kw=vector) (knows its size, handles memory for you, can grow):

```
std::vector<int> grades;
// Allow the user to enter as many numbers as they'd like
for (;;)
{
    int input = 0;
    cout << "Enter a number" endl;
    cin >> input;
    // Store the number. Will continue to grow
    grades.push_back(input);
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I definitely was over complicating what I was trying to do. I was trying to learn something new as I wrote this because I though I would need a dynamic array in order to add more data from the user input and then add it all together. But, your solution is much simpler. And also thanks for explaining why I was wrong with the dynamic array, I didn't realize it was possible to randomly access whatever was in ram like this. Thank you again!